# Drag and drop not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, admin

I created a drag and drop control within C# to allow people to drop files onto my form. Here's the problem I'm having, it works fine when it's being debugged; however when running my program in administrator mode it doesn't work. Is there any reason for this?

Here's my code:

```
private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) 
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

string startDir;

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    dropZoneLabel.Text = "Adding files; please wait...";
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        bool isFolder = File.GetAttributes(file).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);
        if (isFolder)
        {
            //Scan the folder for all files
            DirectoryOperations searchFolders = new DirectoryOperations();
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(file);
            foreach (FileInfo dropfile in searchFolders.FullDirList(di, "*"))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dropfile.Name);
            }
            startDir = di.FullName;
        }
        else
        {
            //It's a file so add it as normal
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
    dropZoneLabel.Text = "Drop files or folders here";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from Windows Vista because of User Interface Privilege Isolation you cannot drag and drop from an application running at lower integrity level to an application which runs on a higher level.

See this article for more details: [Why Doesn’t Drag-and-Drop work when my Application is Running Elevated?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/01/28/q-why-doesn-t-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I used this now http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/03/30/a-quick-start-guide-of-process-mandatory-level-checking-and-self-elevation-under-uac.aspx?Redirected=true, seems like a much better solution.

Comment: @KieranCrown Link is 404.

Comment: @KieranCrown link is not working anymore, can you tell me what was the solution ?

Comment: I found it thanks anyway http://web.archive.org/web/20150116153525/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/03/30/a-quick-start-guide-of-process-mandatory-level-checking-and-self-elevation-under-uac.aspx