# DragDrop for application which required elevated permissions

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, uac

I have an application which requires elevated permissions. In order to support dragdrop from other application they need to be started as administrator. This is not desired, as outlook and file explorer usually is not started with elevated permissions.

Is there a way to allow drag and drop from these applications without starting them as administrator?

Or is there an easy way to find out why my application (VS 2017) requires elevated permissions and see if if I can leave them out?

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21651615/10216583

Comment: Thanks, but that's more or less the reason why it doesn't work. I already know that :)

Comment: Sorry bud. I'll back to you in this one when I find something better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the solution is to "de-elevate" my application. Not sure how to find out what's causing the elevated state though.

Comment: Why does your application require elevated permissions: Is it set to require elevation in the manifest? Does it have a name that looks like a setup program so Windows thinks it needs to elevate it? (The answer depends on your application.)